# Map layer disappears when I change projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using qgis 2.16.1. When I change the projection (using Layer>Set CRS of layer(s), the map disappears. I have attempted to recover the map by changing back to the original projection with no success. How can I change the projection and maintain a visible map?

Comment: **DO** **NOT** use `Set CRS of layer` unless you are told to do so. Use `Save As ...` for vector data and `Raster -> Projection -> Warp` for rasters  to a different filename and CRS instead.